# Why won't mysqld start after a yum update?

Tags: mysql, centos-6

This morning I ran `yum update` and it completed successfully. We noticed, however, that the database server wasn't running. As root, I ran:

```
service mysqld restart
```

Which gave me the following error:

```
[root@ombrelle ~]# service mysqld start
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

And in `mysqld.log` I see the following:

```
141106 08:31:09 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
/usr/libexec/mysqld: File '/var/lib/binary-logs/binary-log.index' not found (Errcode: 13)
141106  8:31:09 [ERROR] Aborting

141106  8:31:09 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

141106 08:31:09 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

This would hint to me it's something to do with permissions? Binary logs are located in `/var/lib/binary-logs`.

```
[root@ombrelle ~]# ls -alZ /var/lib/
...
drwxr-xr-x. mysql   mysql  unconfined_u:object_r:var_lib_t:s0 binary-logs
...
drwxr-xr-x. mysql   mysql  system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 mysql
...
```

And:

```
[root@ombrelle ~]# ls -alZ /var/lib/binary-logs/*.index
-rw-rw----. mysql mysql unconfined_u:object_r:var_lib_t:s0 /var/lib/binary-logs/binary-log.index
```

I've not modified any of these permissions or the MySQL configuration at all. Everything has been working fine for months, with a few restarts using `service mysqld restart` in that time.

We are running Centos 6.5, MySQL server from webatic:

```
mysql55w-server.x86_64                     5.5.40-1.w6                 @webtatic
```

Here is my configuration from `/etc/my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
symbolic-links=0

# replicate (almost) everything...
replicate-wild-ignore-table=mysql.%

# ...but don't pass dev databases on
binlog-do-db=somedb

server-id=666
report-host=ourhost.co.uk
log-bin=/var/lib/binary-logs/binary-log
binlog_format=MIXED
log-slave-updates=1
```

**Update:** I have seen this message in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` from SELinux:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1415263841.315:946413): avc:  denied  { read write } for  pid=49196 comm="mysqld" name="binary-log.index" dev=md2 ino=5646260 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_lib_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1415263841.315:946413): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=f974c0 a1=42 a2=1b0 a3=fffffffffffffffd items=0 ppid=48629 pid=49196 auid=0 uid=27 gid=27 euid=27 suid=27 fsuid=27 egid=27 sgid=27 fsgid=27 tty=pts5 ses=8098 comm="mysqld" exe="/usr/libexec/mysqld" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_t:s0 key=(null)
```

I'm beginning to think I need some specific context on my `binary-logs` folder, and maybe the fact I didn't have this problem before was because it's not been rebooted in a long time? (Though I still don't understand why this wouldn't have been a problem with a simple `service mysqld restart`).

*Update:* I've added an answer that fixes the issues, however the question remains: why did this work before and stop working after I ran `yum update`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it worked before, but the reason it wouldn't start *was* down to SELinux. The context for the `binary-logs` directory was wrong. Looking back at the part of the question that showed the `ls -alZ` of the original `mysql` folder and the later added `binary-logs` one:

```
drwxr-xr-x. mysql   mysql  unconfined_u:object_r:var_lib_t:s0 binary-logs
drwxr-xr-x. mysql   mysql  system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 mysql
```

we see the user and group permissions are indeed fine, but the SELinux context isn't. Running the following:

```
chcon -R -u system_u -r object_r -t mysqld_db_t
```

made it possible to start the server again. If anyone wishes to add an answer on why it worked *before* the update then please feel free and I'll gladly accept your answer. I have edited the question to reflect this.